# Translate cut code to grep regex code for locating and returning up to the first hyphen

Tags: regex, command-line, grep, cut

I have a list of filenames similar to the following:

```
NAME - Something something something
ANOTHER NAME - More stuff
THIRD - This is a title
FOURTH - This is a title - With an extra hyphen
FIFTH NAME - And some more
```

What I would like is to grab just the names up to the first hyphen. That is, my results should be:

```
NAME
ANOTHER NAME
THIRD
FOURTH
FIFTH NAME
```

I was able to accomplish this via `cut -d'-' -f1` but I was wondering what would be a way to translate this into a `grep` command?

I have tried expressions like `grep -o "^[[:upper:]]* -"` but I run into issues when there is a second hyphen contained in the name (e.g. `FOURTH`) and also with names that have more than word (e.g. `ANOTHER NAME` and `FIFTH NAME`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extended flavour, use anchor to the beginning of the line and match every character until if finds a dash, like:

```
grep -oE '^[^-]*' infile
```

It yields:

```
NAME 
ANOTHER NAME 
THIRD 
FOURTH 
FIFTH NAME
```

Comment: This leave a space after the text, not sure if that is a problem.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` should do:

```
awk -F" -" '{print $1}' file
NAME
ANOTHER NAME
THIRD
FOURTH
FIFTH NAME
```

---

Or a `sed` version:

```
sed 's/ -.*//' file
NAME
ANOTHER NAME
THIRD
FOURTH
FIFTH NAME
```